# get one value from multiple values in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, listagg

I tried the below query which returns two values but i need to get one value separated with `','`. For example the query should return result :

```
TRPT,PRLD
```

Below is the query i tried:

```
SELECT     
    LISTAGG(T_NAME, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY T_NAME) "ListValues"
FROM TST_TBL where T_DATE > sysdate-1 
GROUP BY T_NAME
```

It returns:

```
ListValues
    TRPT
    PRLD
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `GROUP BY` clause, it causes your "problems".

```
SQL> with tst_tbl (t_name, t_date) as
  2    (select 'TRPT', sysdate from dual union all
  3     select 'PRLD', sysdate from dual
  4    )
  5  SELECT
  6      LISTAGG(T_NAME, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY T_NAME) "ListValues"
  7  FROM TST_TBL where T_DATE > sysdate-1
  8  /

ListValues
--------------------
PRLD,TRPT

SQL>
```